# Cannot find my Meteor installation on Windows

Tags: windows, meteor, cygwin

I installed it by using the .exe from [link](https://www.meteor.com/install) but I clicked too fast and didn't see what folder it was put in. No big deal, i'll try to reinstall, but it won't let me, it just says, "Hey your done!"... when I search around my C drive, I can't find it, searching doesn't work... I am stumped. I couldn't figure it out after googling either. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the [Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/windows-version-does-not-run-after-install/2322) and it looks like it is located here:

`<Your User folder>/AppData/Local/.meteor.`